Async tasks not properly exited within a FastAPI websocket endpoint
I have a fastapi application that creates a websocket connection initiated by a react frontend. In it, I listen on a certain redis pubsub channel, and whenever a message is posted, I send that message to the front end with the same websocket object. This works as intended.
async def reader(channel: aioredis.client.PubSub, websocket: WebSocket):
    while True:
        try:
            async with async_timeout.timeout(1):
                message = await channel.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
                if message is not None and message['type'] == 'message':    
                    await websocket.send_text(message['data'].decode('utf-8'))

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
            
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)


@router.websocket("/api/ws/{id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, station_id: str, redis: aioredis.Redis = Depends(get_redis)):
    await websocket.accept()
    channel_name = f'updates:{id}'

    try:
        pubsub = redis.pubsub()
        await pubsub.subscribe(channel_name)

        await reader(pubsub, websocket)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("WebSocket disconnected by the client.")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:          
        print("WebSocket connection cancelled.")
    except Exception as e:  
        print('WebSocket error:', e)    
    finally:
        await pubsub.unsubscribe(channel_name)
        await pubsub.close()
        await websocket.close()

The messages posted to the pubsub are created in a celery task initiated in another api endpoint. This works as intended.
I run into problems whenever I try and exit the fastapi application (or if watchfiles detects a change and causes a reload), where it is unable to exit the async operations.
Here is the unicorn and error output:
WARNING:  WatchFiles detected changes in 'server/routes/test_routes.py'. Reloading...
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     connection closed
INFO:     Waiting for background tasks to complete. (CTRL+C to force quit) # <--- FREEZES HERE
^CINFO:     Finished server process [3639091]
ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXX/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 747, in lifespan
    await receive()
  File "XXXXX/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/lifespan/on.py", line 137, in receive
    return await self.receive_queue.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/queues.py", line 159, in get
    await getter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

WebSocket connection cancelled.
INFO:     Stopping reloader process [3638971]

I have tried redis-py and aioredis in different configurations, and some are unable to send to frontend but able to shutdown properly, and others are able to send through the socket but unable to shutdown properly.
I've looked into FastAPI's lifespan for allocating and deallocating redis resources but had troubles with it never reaching the shutdown point.
Nothing has quite stuck yet but any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

I might be wrong, but I'd guess the issue is that nothing in your reader function raises an exception, so that task never ends. You might want to do something like setting an asyncio.Event in the shutdown part of the lifespan handler, which breaks the while True: loop.

I did also try an asyncio.Event that runs in the shutdown portion of lifespan, but it never seems to reach that part. I've verified this with a print statement. So it's not quite exiting the yield portion of the lifespan handler.

In your code, the reader function is an infinite loop that continuously listens for messages from Redis. When the server shuts down, it waits for background tasks to complete, but since the reader task is still running, it never completes, causing the server shutdown process to freeze.
To fix this issue, you need to properly handle the shutdown of the WebSocket reader task when the server is shutting down. One approach is to use a flag to signal the task to stop when the server is shutting down.
